# Installing an additional Kitchen Lighting circuit

Tags: kitchens, light

I would like to install an additional Kitchen Light above a Breakfast Bar as a new circuit but would like to avoid lifting the floorboards on the floor above if possible as it is the bathroom and I would need to dismantle the sink unit and pan. Can I........

(1) Take the live feed to the new switch from an adjacent switch? The switch in question is a 2-way switch but I know that the feed to it is the 'live' feed and not the switch wire. And...

(2) Connect the neutral return from the new light to another light fitting that I can easily access, and am able to identify which is the neutral return and which is the switch wire feeding the light?

For info my Kitchen currently has a single pole switch operating 5 sunken ceiling lights; a 2-way switch operating another 5 sunken ceiling lights; a single pole switch feeding transformers operating under cabinet Halogen lighting and another single pole switch feeding a transformer operating LED plinth lighting.

Comment: Splitting the neutral like that would be a code violation. The hot and neutral must be contained in the same cable. Why wouldn't you use the neutral from the same adjacent switch?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and advice on code violation. The adjacent switch has only the hot feed and the blue & yellow switch wires as it is a 2-way.

Comment: Please clarify what you intend to do. You say "new circuit," which, I believe, implies running cables to a new location in your breaker panel. What you describe, however, is not a new circuit, but a splice into the existing circuit.

Comment: Thanks Hari you are quite right. It is a splice into the existing circuit that will be for a new switch and light fitting.

Comment: I'd like to see a photo of the existing switch box. What you describe doesn't make sense. Any switch box should have either two or four conductors in it.

Comment: Wait. **blue and yellow**!?  That sounds like *conduit*.   If you need a neutral there, you can just pull it.  Most houses are wired with flexible cable, which has specific colors: black, white and sometimes red.  If you see other colors, that's a sure sign there is hard piping between junctions, with individual wires sent down the pipes.  In that type of installation, electricians can and do choose a variety of colors, for clarity.  That's good news.

Comment: Can you please get us a photo of the inside of the switch box?